# After setRotationX/setRotationY Width/Height increase. How to obtain the new width and height?

Tags: android

Here is an example:

[image]

The black image has setRotationX(45). On RotationX = 0 the black image has same width as the red image, but on rotation its width increase.

If i use getWidth, the value is the same at any rotationX value.

Another problem is that the width is different depending on the screen size. For example on tablet the black view looks less wider than the red view.

The only solution I've found for fixing this is to get the width of the rotated view and then use scaleX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that my approach was wrong. For what I want to achieve i must use pivotx and pivoty. By default pivotx and pivoty are set at 50% and that`s why this happens. The solution is to use (pivotx = 50% and pivoty = 0%) or(pivotx = 50% and pivoty = 100%)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using trigonometry. It would look something like `|sin(theta * 2) / 2| + 1` (for a square of width 1). I'm doing this from the top of my head so, make adjustments for accuracy, including adding the part of the function that takes into account the width and height.

Comment: Can you give me more details. Why 4, what is theta?

Comment: `4` because you have four sides of a square and therefor need the period to be `1/4` the normal size. Theta, or `θ`, is the rotation value.

Comment: Not working. WHen theta = 45, 1+sin(theta*4) = 1. I consider this is a factor for multiplying the initial width right?

Comment: Also. I am not sure if this will work. I noticed that the additional width is bigger or smaller depending on the screen size so there must be a different formula.

Comment: This is a general idea of how it should work, not something you could just copy and paste.